Independence of the equations resulting from the action principle $\delta (I_{\text{gravity}} + I_{\text{other fields}}) = 0$
In Dirac's "GTR", Chap. $30$, he discusses the "comprehensive action principle" and shows that variation of the combined action of the Hilbert-Einstein action plus all other matter-energy fields:
$$\delta (I_{\text{gravity}} + I_{\text{other fields}}) = 0$$
results in an equation of the type
$$\delta (I_{\text{gravity}} + I_{\text{other fields}}) = \int \left( p^{μν} δg_{μν} + \sum_{n} \chi^n \delta\phi_n \right) \sqrt{-g} d^4 x$$
Here, in terms of Lagrangians:
\begin{align}
δ(I_{\text{g}}+I_{\text{of}}) &= \int δL_{g}\sqrt{-g}\, d^4 x + \int δL_{\text{of}} (g_{μν},ϕ_n,ϕ_{n,μ})\sqrt{-g}\, d^4 x\\
 &=-\frac{1}{16π} \int \left( R^{μν}-\frac{1}{2} g^{μν} R \right) δg_{μν} \sqrt{-g}\, d^4 x + \int δL_{\text{of}}\sqrt{-g}\, d^4 x.
\end{align}
So we suppose the other matter-energy fields have a Lagrangian $L_{\text{of}} (g_{μν},ϕ_n,ϕ_{n,μ})$. In the action integral, the $ϕ_{n,μ}$ terms are converted to $ϕ_{n}$ terms using integration by parts. The $p^{\mu\nu}$ term includes whatever terms in $\delta g_{\mu\nu}$ come from $\delta I_{\text{of}}$. Specifically:
$$p^{μν} = -\frac{1}{16π} (R^{μν}-\frac{1}{2} g^{μν} R) + N^{μν}$$ where $N^{μν}$ is the coefficient of $\delta g_{\mu\nu}$ in $\delta I_{\text{of}}$.
So, the action principle generates the equations
$$p^{\mu\nu}=0,$$
$$\chi^n=0$$
QUESTION: Dirac shows that $N^{μν}_{\ \ \ \ \ ;\nu}=0$ and then says, "on account of this relation, the equations
$$p^{\mu\nu}=0,$$
$$\chi^n=0$$
are not all independent."
Can someone clarify how he deduces this?
